# Spring Boot: error=“invalid_grant”, error_description=“Bad credentials”

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-oauth2

I am trying to use AuthorizationServer and ResourceServer in Spring Boot.
Code for AuthorizationServer is like this

````
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    static final String CLIEN_ID = "client";
    static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "$2a$04$e/c1/RfsWuThaWFCrcCuJeoyvwCV0URN/6Pn9ZFlrtIWaU/vj/BfG";
    static final String GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD = "password";
    static final String AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "authorization_code";
    static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "refresh_token";
    static final String IMPLICIT = "implicit";
    static final String SCOPE_READ = "read";
    static final String SCOPE_WRITE = "write";
    static final String TRUST = "trust";
    static final int ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 1*60*60;
    static final int FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS = 6*60*60;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter() {
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();
        converter.setSigningKey("as466gf");
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer configurer) throws Exception {

        configurer
                .inMemory()
                .withClient(CLIEN_ID)
                .secret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                .authorizedGrantTypes(GRANT_TYPE_PASSWORD, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, REFRESH_TOKEN, IMPLICIT )
                .scopes(SCOPE_READ, SCOPE_WRITE, TRUST)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(ACCESS_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS).
                refreshTokenValiditySeconds(FREFRESH_TOKEN_VALIDITY_SECONDS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .accessTokenConverter(accessTokenConverter());
    }
}```

Code for ResourceServer is like this


```@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private static final String RESOURCE_ID = "resource_id";

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
        resources.resourceId(RESOURCE_ID).stateless(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.
                anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/users/**").access("hasRole('ADMIN')")
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(new OAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    }

}```

Then the code for WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is like this

```@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .anonymous().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api-docs/**").permitAll();
    }



    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
````

So whenever I try to hit this url `{{BASE_URL}}/oauth/token` I am getting this error

````
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}```


I am using PostMan to use the api. I have provided a username and a password as the Basic Auth. I don't know what is missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.
````

Answer (score 0):

Your api call should be like this:

[image]

Don't forget to click on PREVIEW REQUEST in Authorization tab

Comment: I am doing that too

Comment: Buddy, I've made a implementation of securtiy with oAuth2 in a project:
https://github.com/pietroow/fisiopar-spring/tree/develop
Try to test it and give me a feedback